# Why does Spring Framework consider method names only for deciding if a bean can be skipped?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans, spring-context

## Background

I came across a piece of code that looks something like this -

```java
public class TestClass {

    @Profile("profile")
    @Bean(name = "beanMethodName") //I know this is not an accurate way of adding qualifier
    public Function<String, String> beanMethodName(final String arg) {
        // Do something
    }

    @Profile("!profile")
    @Bean(name = "beanMethodName")
    public Function<String, String> beanMethodName(final String arg1, final String arg2) {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

Now, when I start this Spring application for **profile = test**, then the Bean
**beanMethodName** never gets created.

## Root Cause

The reason why this happens is how Spring decides which beans to create and which ones to skip.
The following code block exists in **ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader** -

```java
// Do we need to mark the bean as skipped by its condition?
if (this.conditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(metadata, ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN)) {
    configClass.skippedBeanMethods.add(methodName);
    return;
}
if (configClass.skippedBeanMethods.contains(methodName)) {
    return;
}
```

Ref -

- [Spring Framework 5.1.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.1.x/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java#L180-L187)
- [Spring Framework 6.0.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/6.0.x/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java#L182-L189)
- [Spring Framework main](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java#L182-L189)

The first check for `this.conditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(metadata, ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN)` results in **TRUE** since the Condition for `Profile` doesn't match. The `Bean Method Name` is added to the `skippedBeanMethods`. The second `Bean Method Name` check for `this.conditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(metadata, ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN)` results in **FALSE**, but later in the second `if...` block the bean registration is skipped again since the `Bean Method Name` is present in `skippedBeanMethods`

## The Problem / Question

The current code block forces the developers to use a separate method name for the bean even if it can probably be an override for a different profile.

I've read in some places that the order of beans defined in the **Configuration** can help, but that still means that it would fail in the other profile where the non-matching-profile bean comes first.

#### Question

Why can't the code be modified to be something like this?

```java
// Do we need to mark the bean as skipped by its condition?
boolean shouldSkip = this.conditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(metadata, ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN);
if (configClass.skippedBeanMethods.contains(methodName) && shouldSkip) {
    return;
} else if (shouldSkip) {
    configClass.skippedBeanMethods.add(methodName);
    return;
}
```

This decouples the `Bean Method Name` from the **skippedBeanMethods** check.

- If a `Bean Method Name` is present in the `skippedBeanMethods` **AND** for the Condition evaluator results in `shouldSkip(..)` returning **TRUE**, then the bean is skipped.
- If a `Bean Method Name` is not present in the `skippedBeanMethods` **AND** for the Condition evaluator results in `shouldSkip(..)` returning **TRUE**, then the bean is skipped and it is added to the `skippedBeanMethods`.
- In all other cases, it would still allow bean registration.

In other words, the bean registration will be skipped **if and only if** a Condition Evaluator results in `shouldSkip(..)` returning **TRUE** for the `Bean Method Name`.

#### Note

- I understand that the issue here can be resolved by using a different `Bean Method Name` or by using appropriate `Qualifier`.
- What I am trying to understand is why can't the bean registration be decoupled from the `Bean Method Names`?